# Can we have more than 4 stage3Ds in flash?

Tags: flash, stage3d

I can't seem to find a way to get more than the initial set of 4 stage3Ds provided by flash.

I have tried instantiating a new one using it's constructor and then adding it to the stage by simply pushing it to the list

```
stage.stage3Ds.push(new Stage3D());
```

but this doesn't seem to be working as my eventListener for the Event.CONTEXT3D_CREATE is never called (it is if I use one of the default Stage3Ds.

Does anybody have a workaround or a way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Adobe documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage3D.html):

> Stage3D provides a high-performance rendering surface for content
>   rendered using the Context3D class. This surface uses the graphics
>   processing unit (GPU) when possible. The runtime stage provides a
>   fixed number of Stage3D objects. The number of instances varies by the
>   type of device. Desktop computers typically provide four Stage3D
>   instances.

So: No.  And you shouldn't assume you'll always have four at your disposal, either - there might be less.